# Spring Boot doesn't pick spring.datasource.tomcat.* while programmatically configuring datasources?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am configuring two data sources, and trying to set pooling properties and as per docs I should use spring.datasource.tomcat.*, that doesn't seem to work with the configuration that I am doing. What am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?

My application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username
spring.datasource.password

spring.read.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.read.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1 
spring.read.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.read.datasource.username
spring.read.datasource.password
```

Below is my configuration class : 
I have a similar one for read data source (for different repo/entities)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
basePackages = "com.test.feature.repo.internal")
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean("dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, 
            @Qualifier("dataSource")DataSource dataSource){
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.test.feature.entity.internal").persistenceUnit("defaultPersistenceUnit").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

If I try to use spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true, then this works.

I really want to know why the .tomcat.* style doesn't work? And what I can I do to make that work?

Even if someone redirects me to some helpful reading material for understanding this, I will be glad. :)

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.4

Comment: Same happens to me in 1.5.7. DataSource is not picking up `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` properties. For me even spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true is not working.

Comment: Logged a issue here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10845

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That documentation is about the auto-configuration and you're not using it. If you are writing custom code to setup the `DataSource`, you are in charge of the binding of the configuration as well.

Your code above has a `@ConfigurationPropeties("spring.datasource")`. If you remove that, none of the `spring.datasource.*` properties would be taken into account in your own code.

[This section of the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) explains the difference between basic properties (`spring.datasource`) and data source binding (`spring.datasource.xyz.*`).

Regardless, if you are creating the `DataSource` yourself (why?) then use a separate namespace. Reusing the `spring.datasource` namespace is quite confusing as a user is expecting that the features the auto-configuration provides will be honoured. And they won't since you're writing your own config.

Comment: Then how to configure multiple datasources such that pool properties are not affected. (tomcat jdbc pool in this case). The documentation does not covers this anywhere.

Comment: The doc covers exactly that (I gave a link in my answer). Have you looked at it?

Comment: Found it. I was missing that connection properties can also be specified in the same namespace. Thanks for your help

Comment: I was creating two datasource beans myself as I wanted to connect to one write data source and one read datasource, and enable jpa repos for both based on package name.

Comment: This was very helpful! We updated all our microservices to the new pool specific config including one that had two data sources. It's not very intuitve, that we need `*datasource.tomcat.*` for auto configured data sources and omit the pool name for manually configured ones. Before introducing pool specific properties, the structure was the same for both auto-configured and manual data sources. However, I have to admit that it absolutely makes sense from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I have added  following two lines in my `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.read.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

It is working...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you only have one datasource and auto-configuration, you only need to use  spring.datasource.* to config. tomcatcp will be selected as a default cp.
2. In your case: configure two dataSources programmatically , please add the following annotation **spring.datasource.type** in your **application.properties** to tell it which connection pool you choose.

`spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.read.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`

Answer (score 0):

Problem i was encountering was similiar to yours. I was trying to set the datasource connections externally, and i wanted to utilize spring's autoconfiguration operations too. So what i learned was to use a  environmentpostprocessor to modify the properties and Spring to use the changed ones.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ExternalDataSourceEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        // Get the MutablePropertySources
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();

        // Remove existing properties
        propertySources.remove("spring.datasource.url");
        propertySources.remove("spring.datasource.username");
        propertySources.remove("spring.datasource.password");

        // Generate random values for properties
        String randomUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String randomUsername = "user" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String randomPassword = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Add random properties
        Properties randomProperties = new Properties();
        randomProperties.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", randomUrl);
        randomProperties.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", randomUsername);
        randomProperties.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", randomPassword);

        propertySources.addLast(
            new PropertiesPropertySource("external-datasource", randomProperties)
        );
    }
}
```

Check this link out for more info.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor