# Spring boot default connection pool tomcat properties not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jdbc, jdbctemplate

We are using spring boot **1.5.9.RELEASE**. We have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `mysql-connector-java` in our maven dependency to connect to MySQL db. We have not configured any connection pool. According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) since we are using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` tomcat connection pool is used as default connection pool. But when we try setting connection pool properties as `spring.datasource.tomcat.*`  it is not working. But the same is working when `spring.datasource.*` format is used.

i.e `spring.datasource.max-active=50` is working where as `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50` is not working. I confirmed this by printing Datasource in main class for which I'm getting `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@<objecthash>{key1=value1; key2=value2; ....}` as output.

Why is this happening? Is it because we are using `mysql-connector-java` it's not reading tomcat connection pool properties? if that's the case then when I print Datasource how am I getting `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@a1f72f5` as data source with configured values? Or did I miss out something from the documentation? or JPA is not working properly?

**pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Mainclass.java**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClassChild.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);

    }
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/dbname?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Working
spring.datasource.max-active=30
spring.datasource.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.min-idle=10

#Not Working
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=10
```

Note: We autowire `jdbctemplate` and use it in `DAO`.

Comment: 1st: spring boot 1.5.x EOL has been announced. 2nd: Please post a MCVE, including your config class and application.yaml.

Comment: application.properties included. Hope that helps. Also added a note.

Comment: Try adding this `spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`. You could be using [Hikari which is Spring default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) even if tomcat pool is available.

Comment: no change. It's already using tomcat pooling. As mentioned in Note, printing datasource print's `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` object.

Comment: Are you mixing keys as in your question? This is the url: spring.datasource.url, and this is max-active: spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active? They should be consistent.

Comment: I didn't understand ur query. I've separated working config and non working config.

Comment: If using tomcat pool all porperties should use that key, e.g. `spring.datasource.tomcat.url`

Comment: Are you sure? because there is no such property called `spring.datasource.tomcat.url` and trying that throws error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216222/2834978

Comment: Yeah. The answer applies when you have created/configured a datasource. But in my case we have not configured anything. Its auto configured

Comment: @Mani I can't reproduce this. `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` seems to work fine. Make sure that you're running actually on Spring boot 1.5.x, as older versions of Spring boot did use `spring.datasource.*` to configure a datasource. Also make sure you're not creating your own `DataSource` bean somewhere.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz That's wrong, main properties such as the URL, username and password should be configured through `spring.datasource.*`. All other vendor-related configuration should be configured through `spring.datasource.tomcat.*`. You can verify that in [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: @g00glen00b we haven't configured any Datasource, But even if we have done that how come `spring.datasource.max-active` will affecting that? Also, as mentioned When I print Datasource it's reflecting the properties set as above.

Comment: @Mani Yeah, I did the same thing, copied your code, used a different `max-active` amount for the working/not working scenario, and when I take a look at the console, I see the amount configured for `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active`. To answer your other question, if you created your own `DataSource` bean, you can choose how you configure the `maxActive` property yourself, you could even make it so that it reads from `spring.datasource.max-active` in stead of `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active`, so that's why I was asking it, just to be sure that this wasn't the case.